# Comparing values in two columns and returning values on conditional bases using sql hive

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have two columns, I want to get an output based on a comparative basis of both. My data is somewhat like:

```
Customer Id   status
100           A
100           B
101           B
102           A
103           A
103           B
```

So a customer can have a status A or B or both, I have to segrerate them on customer id basis for a status. If status A and B then return happy, if only A, return Avg and if only B return Sad.

Comment: is it one column that holds status value? have u consider using case?

Answer (score 0):

try the below query,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Customer_Id,
        (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_Id) > 1 THEN 'happy'
        WHEN Tstatus = 'A' THEN 'Avg'
        ELSE 'Sad'END)  AS  New_Status
FROM    @table1
GROUP BY Customer_Id,Tstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

if Customer Id and status is a unique combination then
STEP 1: use case to determine a or b

```
SELECT customer id
  ,CASE WHEN avg(case when [status] ='A' then 0 else 2 end)
FROM [Your Table]
group by[customer id]
```

and step 2 will be casing avg into result: like this

```
SELECT customer id
  ,CASE WHEN (avg(case when [status] ='A' then 0 else 2 end)) = 1 THEN 'happy' ELSE WHEN (avg(case when [status] ='A' then 0 else 2 end)) = 0 THEN 'Avg' ELSE 'Sad' END
FROM [Your Table]
group by[customer id]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this simply as:

```
select customer_id,
       (case when min(status) <> max(status) then 'happy'
             when min(status) = 'A' then 'avg'
             else 'sad'
        end)
from t
where status in ('A', 'B')
group by customer_id
```